# Accessing Knockout component DOM from required AMD viewModel

Tags: knockout.js, requirejs, amd

I load my Knockout component this way:

```
ko.components.register("example", {
    viewModel: {require: "widgets/example"},
    template:  {require: "text!widgets/example.html"}
});
```

with `example.js` (extremely simplified):

```
"use strict";

define(["knockout"], function(ko) {

    function ExampleWidgetViewModel(params) {

        this.editedText = ko.observable("Example");
    }

    return ExampleWidgetViewModel;
});
```

and `example.html`:

```
<div id="example-dlg", data-bind="text: editedText"></div>
```

The component is called as usual as `<example></example>` and everything works perfectly. But I want to access the DOM to remove the need of the `id` in the template.
Tried [the method from the documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/component-registration.html#highlighter_535973) changing `example.js` to be:

```
"use strict";

define(["knockout"], function(ko) {

    function ExampleWidgetViewModel(params, componentInfo) {

        this.editedText = ko.observable("Example");
    }

    return {createViewModel: ExampleWidgetViewModel};
});
```

But it complains that `editedText` is not found. Same problem with other variations like this:

```
"use strict";

define(["knockout"], function(ko) {

    function creaExample(params, componentInfo) {
        let ExampleWidgetViewModel = (params) => {

             this.editedText = ko.observable("Example");
        }
        return ExampleWidgetViewModel;
    }
    return {createViewModel: creaExample};
});
```

Could you provide a working example? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing better than asking for help to find a solution... I was wrongly calling the view model. The correct `example.js` file is:

```
"use strict";

define(["jquery", "knockout"], function($, ko) {

    function factory(params, componentInfo) {
        function ViewModel() {

            // To show how to access the component external div
            console.log($(componentInfo.element.firstChild).attr("id"));

            // To show it can correctly access parameters
            this.editedText = params.oneParameter;
        }
        return new ViewModel();
    }
    return {createViewModel: factory};
});
```